# .htaccess file using 2 different rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've got a .htaccess file that has got a rewrite rule in it as follows which works fine:

```
RewriteRule ^solicitorsin([^/]+)/all/([0-9]+)$ /search/searchresults.php?county=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

What I'm looking to do is to keep using this for if the page variable is 2 or higher, but if it's 1 I want to 301 redirect to a separate url (the same site) say `http://www.domain.com/solicitorsinCOUNTY/`

The problem is that if I try doing this using a 301 redirect or a rewrite rule it still performs the above rewrite rule as well so I end up with `http://www.domain.com/solicitorsinCOUNTY/?county=COUNTY&page=1`

I haven't done much with .htaccess before so I'm not even sure if this is possible, can anyone help please? It would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a rewrite rule, then put the rule for `page=1` above the other rule and make sure you have the `[L]` flag.

Alternatively, you can use `RewriteCond` to prevent the rule from being run on specific URLS like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^solicitorsin([^/]+)/all/1$
RewriteRule ^solicitorsin([^/]+)/all/([0-9]+)$ /search/searchresults.php?county=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you :)

If I have the line as this:
RewriteRule ^solicitorsin([^/]+)/all/1$ http://www.domain.com/solicitorsin$1/ [r=301,L]

Will that then mean it's a 301 redirect setup on each of the old /all/1 links? Or do I need to setup a manual 301 redirect for each one?

Comment: @user: Not sure what you mean. It will redirect anything matching the pattern.